# Livepatch fails on 2nd personal machine

Tags: update-manager, 22.04, canonical-livepatch

I have a personal token for livepatch on my laptop and it works fine.  I added livepatch using my token to my wife's laptop, but she still gets updater even though the livepatch icon shows in the tray.  Both PCs are running 22.04.  Anything I can do?

Comment: Your problem description is not clear, you state "she still gets updater" Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: Instead of Livepatch update occurring with no intervention, the "Software Updater" pop-up opens with the updates, and must be manually activated.